# DataFrameReadercsv(path: String) option for skipping blank lines

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Does

```
org.apache.spark.sqlDataFrameReadercsv(path: String)
```

have an option for skipping blank lines?  In particular, a blank line as the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting `mode` to `"DROPMALFORMED"` as in:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")...
```

In `Python`:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(mode = "DROPMALFORMED")...
```

Which according to the [documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv):

> "...drops lines which have fewer or more tokens than expected."

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:

value options is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: I think Python syntax is used above. For Scala, use spark.read.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").csv(path)