# How to read json file to spark dataframe without those data have null value in some column?

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, struct, nullable

My data is like this:

```
{"id":"1","time":123,"sth":100} 
{"id":"2","sth":456} 
{"id":"3","time":789,"sth":300}
```

And I write my schema as:

```
StructType(
  Array(
    StructField("id", StringType, false),
    StructField("time", StringType, false),
    StructField("sth", StringType, true),
  )  
)
```

And I read my data using:

```
val df = spark.read.schema(buildSchema()).json(path)
```

What I want is that my dataframe doesn't read those lines without "time" value, so the result I want is

| id | time | sth |
| 1  | 123  | 100 |
| 3  | 789  | 300 |

However, even I set the nullable attribute as false in my StructField, it still read the second line `{"id":"2","sth":456}` into my table, and I need to waste time to drop those rows with null value after reading. Is there any way to do what I want efficiently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataFrameReadercsv(path: String) option for skipping blank lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476254/dataframereadercsvpath-string-option-for-skipping-blank-lines)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this,

```
    val otherPeopleRDD = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(
          """[{"id":"1","time":123,"sth":100} ,
        {"id":"2","sth":456} ,
        {"id":"3","time":789,"sth":300} ] """ :: Nil)


        val otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleRDD).na.drop()
        otherPeople.show()


+---+---+----+
| id|sth|time|
+---+---+----+
|  1|100| 123|
|  3|300| 789|
+---+---+----+
```